# Method for downloading a PDF from a website in Android

Tags: java, android

How is this? Any ways to improve?

```
public void DownloadPDF(Uri uri) {
    downloadProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    downloadComplete.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    openFile.setText("Wait..."); // My button
    openFile.setEnabled(false);
    if (uri != null) {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setTitle(pdf + ".pdf");
        request.setDescription("Website: " + pdf);
        request.setMimeType("application/pdf");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        }
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/SavedPDFs/", pdf + ".pdf");
        manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);
        onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
                try {
                    unregisterReceiver(onComplete);
                } catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                downloadComplete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                downloadProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                downloadStatus.setText("Download Complete!");
                updateNumberOfFiles();
                openFile.setText("Open!");
                openFile.setEnabled(true);
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(onComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android's method naming convention follows that of Java, so your method name `DownloadPDF()` will probably be better written as `downloadPDF()` (or maybe even `downloadPdf()`).

Your `null` check for `uri` comes in after you have toggled your UI elements, wouldn't that mean the state is possibly inconsistent if the method really received a `null` argument, *and then* the UL elements already indicated the code is downloading something? You may want to return from your method first in this case...

```
public void downloadPdf(URL uri) {
    if (uri == null) {
        return;
    }
    // ...
}
```

`DownloadManager.Request` methods return the object itself, so you may also consider daisy-chaining the setters together:

```
request.setTitle(pdf + ".pdf")
    .setDescription("Website: " + pdf)
    .setMimeType("application/pdf");
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I add a progress bar to this download method? Also, am I handling the onComplete properly?

Comment: @Faraz unfortunately I do not know much about Android development beyond Java...